# is there any difference between writing code like first Imports System.IO then use FileInfo

Tags: .net, vb.net

is there any issue with performance for coding style1 with coding style 2

**Coding style 1**: (HERE FIRST IMPORTS statement then code)
imports SYSTEM.IO

```
Dim Files() As FileInfo = DirInfo.GetFiles(FileMask(j), IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

**Coding Style 2**: (here directly putting System.IO.FileInfo(.....)).

```
Dim Files() As System.IO.FileInfo = DirInfo.GetFiles(FileMask(j), IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

if yes then what which one is better and why?

Comment: How would you define the word "better" in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the IL emitted for this code

```
Dim Files() = Directory.GetFiles("d:\temp", "*.txt")

IL_0000:  ldstr       "d:\temp"
IL_0005:  ldstr       "*.txt"
IL_000A:  call        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles
IL_000F:  pop         
IL_0010:  ret
```

and the IL emitted for this code

```
Dim Files() = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("d:\temp", "*.txt")

IL_0000:  ldstr       "d:\temp"
IL_0005:  ldstr       "*.txt"
IL_000A:  call        System.IO.Directory.GetFiles
IL_000F:  pop         
IL_0010:  ret
```

You could see that there is no difference whatsoever. The compiler always uses the fully qualified name of the class, so, in these simple cases `Imports` is a convenience for the programmer to avoid a lot of repetitive typing.

However, missing to write a specific namespace could have some importance if you have classes with the same name but in different namespaces. In this case you are forced to disambiguate between the two classes using the appropriate namespace or using alias, see more Info on the [MSDN page for Imports statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)